# iPython debugger not providing any insight

Tags: python, debugging, ipython, pdb, ipdb

Let's say I have the following function:

```
def simple_func():
    a = 4
    b = 5
    c = a * b
    print c
```

Here's what I get when I run `%debug simple_func()`:

```
NOTE: Enter 'c' at the ipdb>  prompt to continue execution.
None
> <string>(1)<module>()

ipdb>
```

If I enter `n` the debugger spits 20 back out at me and returns `None`.

This is a simplified version of what's happening across functions, interpreters, machines, etc. What's going on? Why can't I get any of my debuggers to do what I want, when all I need is to do some very simple line-by-line stepping through?

Comment: Did you try setting a breakpoint?

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like `debug` works with a function that's simply defined in the `ipython` session.  It needs to be imported from a file (that is, the `--breakpoint` parameter takes a file name and line).

If I create a file `test.py`

```
In [9]: cat test.py
def simple_func():
    a = 4
    b = 5
    c = a * b
    print(c)
```

I can do:

```
In [10]: import test

In [11]: %debug --breakpoint test.py:1 test.simple_func()
Breakpoint 1 at /home/paul/mypy/test.py:1
NOTE: Enter 'c' at the ipdb>  prompt to continue execution.
> /home/paul/mypy/test.py(2)simple_func()
1     1 def simple_func():
----> 2     a = 4
      3     b = 5
      4     c = a * b
      5     print(c)

ipdb> n
> /home/paul/mypy/test.py(3)simple_func()
1     1 def simple_func():
      2     a = 4
----> 3     b = 5
      4     c = a * b
      5     print(c)

ipdb> n
> /home/paul/mypy/test.py(4)simple_func()
      2     a = 4
      3     b = 5
----> 4     c = a * b
      5     print(c)
      6 

ipdb> a,b
(4, 5)
ipdb> n
> /home/paul/mypy/test.py(5)simple_func()
      2     a = 4
      3     b = 5
      4     c = a * b
----> 5     print(c)
      6 

ipdb> c
20
ipdb> c
20
ipdb> q
```

There may be other ways of using this, but this seems to be simplest, most straight forward one.  I rarely use the debugger.  Instead I test code snippets interactively in Ipython, and sprinkle my scripts with debugging `prints`.